# webpack prevent duplicate sass imports resulting in duplicate css

Tags: webpack, sass

Im currently trying to optimize my webpack output.
My setup consists of multiple entry files. A commons.scss(Global css-file), a fonts.scss(Differed fonts file for optimized loading) and entries for pages with custom css, which is only used on that pages.

This setup works all in all very good except one problem: In some of the entries for the pages I need some stuff from bootstrap(e.g. mixins etc.). When running webpack I end up having the css-classes in both files(common.css and the css for the page-entry), resulting in duplicate code, slower page-loading and strange behaviours.

Now my question is, if there is maybe any plugin, where I can define a global-entry, so that on export the css is not exported into both files.